# PHP script stops after 20-30 seconds

Tags: php, apache

I'm running a script that should run for at least 30 minutes but the script stops after 30 seconds...

I'm not sure why as it worked on other server before.

Is there somewhere I need to check?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max Execution Time Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705795/max-execution-time-errors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
set_time_limit(0); 
ignore_user_abort(true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

You can also edit php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 60; //Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60; //Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to tweak the `max_execution_time` value in the php.ini file. Keep in mind that installations of PHP often keep a php.ini file for the server and one for the command line interpreter. Make sure that you edit the right one.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time